Excel VBA If statement when user hits ESC but not when they click ok on the application.inputbox
I have the following script that allows the user to add a new sheet within the excel workbook, however if the user hits ESC or clicks CANCEL, the msgbox works and the EXIT SUB works, however, when the user clicks OK without entering any characters to name the sheets, the EXIT SUB works but the message doesn't appear??
Section of the below code that I cannot get to function correctly starts at
If APRef = False Or Len(APRef) = 0 Then
WPCheck = MsgBox("No WP reference entered, process cancelled", vbCritical)
Exit Sub

Code
Sub AddWPApd()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wk As String
Dim APRef As String
Dim APDsc As String
Dim APResult As Integer

APResult = 0

wk = ActiveSheet.Name

On Error GoTo ExitWPAddition

If ActiveSheet.Index <= 14 Then

Error = MsgBox("You are not permitted to add a WP in this section, it is only possible to add working papers from Sheets " & """HC010""" & " onwards.", vbExclamation)

Else
    
    APRef = UCase(Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter WP Appendix Ref, eg HC010.a1 for Turnover Appendices.", Title:="WP Appendices Ref", Type:=2))

    If APRef = False Or Len(APRef) = 0 Then
    
        WPCheck = MsgBox("No WP reference entered, process cancelled", vbCritical)
        Exit Sub
        
    Else
    
        For k = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(k).Index > 14 Then
            If APRef = Sheets(k).Name Then
                If vbYes = MsgBox("Sheet already exists, do you want to go to that WP?", vbYesNo) Then Sheets(APRef).Select
                APResult = APResult + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        Next k
        
        If APResult = 0 Then
        APDsc = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter WP Description, eg Top 20 Customers CY 'v' PY.", Title:="WP Appendices Description", Type:=2)
        
        
        Sheets("Add WP").Visible = True
    
        Sheets("Add WP").Copy After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = UCase(APRef)
        ActiveSheet.Range("D6") = StrConv(APDsc, vbProperCase)
        
        Sheets("Add WP").Visible = False
        
        Dim ShCount As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
        ShCount = Sheets.Count
        
        
        For i = 1 To ShCount - 1
            For j = i + 1 To ShCount
                If Sheets(i).Index > 14 Then
                If UCase(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase(Sheets(i).Name) Then
                    Sheets(j).Move before:=Sheets(i)
                End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        
        Call Sort
        
        End If
        
        Sheets(APRef).Select

    End If

End If

ExitWPAddition:

    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


If the user hits ESC, CANCEL, or clicks OK without entering any characters to name the new sheet, the message box should display error message then exit the sub, however, it only displays when hitting ESC or CANCEL, not the OK, but all options still EXIT SUB

Input Box Vs Error Handler
Input Box

You are trying to compare a Boolean with a String which would raise Run-time error '13': Type mismatch but your poor error handling hides the error.

You could have used If APRef = "False" Or Len(APRef) = 0 Then which I have seen often but consider inaccurate.

Also, don't forget to restore the settings that you have turned off at the beginning of the code when exiting.

IMO, the way to go is the following:
Dim APRef As Variant, IsInputValid As Boolean

APRef = UCase(Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Please enter WP Appendix Ref, eg HC010.a1 for Turnover Appendices.", _
    Title:="WP Appendices Ref", Type:=2)) 

If Vartype(APRef) <> vbBoolean Then ' user pressed 'OK' 
    If Len(APRef) <> 0 Then ' user entered at least one character
        IsInputValid = True       
    'Else ' user pressed 'OK' but entered nothing
    End If
'Else ' user pressed 'Cancel'
End If

If Not IsInputValid Then       
    MsgBox "No WP reference entered, process cancelled", _
        vbExclamation ' it's not the end of the World
    Goto ProcExit ' to restore the settings that you turned off
End If


Either implement a Boolean (see above) or place an appropriate message box in each Else statement. That is what the Application.InputBox method is for, to distinguish between these two cases. If you don't need this functionallity, use the InputBox Function instead and simply check for the length of the input.


Error Handling

Handle errors more appropriately, e.g.:
ProcExit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub 
ExitWPAddition:
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub



